# How do I launch a particular URL the same time daily in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, command-prompt

I want to launch a particular URL in chrome every day at the same time. How can I achieve this using command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first being from a single command line. You will want to create a new task in `Task Scheduler` and have it run a command at a desired time. If you wish to use a different browser that supports command lines, be sure to use `_` for any spaces in the directory path.

**Command line:**

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "New_Task" /TR "start "C:\Program_Files_(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.stackoverflow.com" /ST 09:00
```

The second option is to use a `batch` file you store somewhere and it will be called to using the `SchTasks`. Simply create the `site1.bat` and place it somewhere safe example `C:\Windows\My Tasks`.

**From Batch:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@set Task_Name=Task1
@Set Time=09:00
@set Site=www.stackoverflow.com

schtasks /query /TN "%Task_Name%" >NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (goto :EXISTS) ELSE (goto :CREATE)

:CREATE
Set Folder=%~dp0
Set Name=%~nx0

Echo Task does not already exist, creating it now.
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "%Task_Name%" /TR "%Folder%%Name%" /ST %Time%
goto :eof

:EXISTS
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %Site%
goto :eof
```